# SQL if condition for value

Tags: sql

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT Question_ID, Question, department FROM TPM_Questions_Default
```

Now I need to another value to it called selected, this can either be true or false.

I have another table called customerQuestions which has a Question_ID, Customer_ID and selected value (true or false)

What I am trying to do is return all the Questions in TPM_Questions_Default and if Question_ID for the Customer_ID exist use that selected, if it does not mark selected as false.

I have tried using an inner join, but that only returns the questions associated with the customer_ID and not all the questions.

I hope this make sense.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention at the end of this query when its done, I will need to use WHERE Customer_ID = 123456 to get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is a little confusing, but I think this is what you want.  The outer join makes sure you get everything from TPM_Questions_Default and only what matches from customerQuestions.  Then, if customerQuestions.selected = true, you get that - otherwise, you get false (C.selected will be NULL for rows that don't join to Q)

```
SELECT
    Q.Question_ID
    , Q.Question
    , Q.Department
    , C.CustomerId
    , CASE
        WHEN C.selected = true THEN true
        ELSE false
      END AS Selected
FROM 
    TPM_Questions_Default AS Q
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    customerQuestions AS C ON Q.Question_ID = C.Question_ID
```

Also, I put CustomerID in the selection assuming that the question_id might exist more than once in customerQuestions (for each customer that answered).

**SMALL UPDATE:** See @CSL's comment about using COALESCE() instead of the case statement.  Same general idea, just cleaner syntax.  Also, both are somewhat dependent on the datatype of the selected column.  If it is a bit value, you would be comparing and returning 0 and 1 (as opposed to true and false).  And, of course, if it is character data, it would be 'true' and 'false'

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

@user979331 wanted to add WHERE Customer_ID = 1234567.  Because Customer_ID is in the customerQuestions table, this converts the OUTER JOIN into an implicit INNER JOIN.  To work around this, the condition is moved to the JOIN below

```
SELECT
    Q.Question_ID
    , Q.Question
    , Q.Department
    , C.Customer_Id
    , COALESCE(C.selected, 0) AS Selected
FROM 
    TPM_Questions_Default AS Q
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    customerQuestions AS C ON Q.Question_ID = C.Question_ID AND C.Customer_ID = 1234567
```

Comment: I would use `COALESE(C.Selected, 0) as Selected` instead of the Case Statement.

Comment: I understand the confusion, I forgot to mention something, at the end of the query I am using WHERE Customer_ID = 1234567 and all I want is the selected value (true or false) WHERE Customer_ID = 1234567 while returning all the questions. Adding WHERE Customer_ID = 1234567 to your solutions only returns questions associated with the Customer_ID

Comment: When you add the Customer_ID condition, you change the outer join to an implicit INNER join (because it can only match records in customerQuestions).  I'll update the answer with a work-around.